# Why can't VLC see my webcam's microphone?

Tags: sound, video, webcam, vlc

My goal is to stream my webcam over https.  Any recommendations beyond webcam-server and cvlc are welcome.

From VLC, I can say

```
Media -> Open Capture Device
```

and leave the `video 4 linux 2` capture mode selected.  If I then select any of

- /dev/video0
- /dev/v4l/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:2:1.0-video-index0
- /dev/v4l/by-id/usb-Dynex_Dynex_1.3MP_Webcam-video-index0

for a video source and press "Play", I see my video.  If I try to include

```
/dev/snd/by-id/usb-Dynex_Dynex_1.3MP_Webcam-02
```

in the audio, I get the error

```
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'alsa:///dev/snd/by-id/usb-Dynex_Dynex_1.3MP_Webcam-02'.  Check the log for details.
```

Using alternative versions of the microphone gives the same error.  e.g.

```
$ pwd
/dev/snd/by-id
$ ls                                     
usb-Dynex_Dynex_1.3MP_Webcam-02
$ file usb\-Dynex_Dynex_1.3MP_Webcam\-02 
usb-Dynex_Dynex_1.3MP_Webcam-02: symbolic link to `../controlC1'
```

suggests I should use `/dev/snd/controlC1`, but that yields the same MRL...alsa:/// error.  Also, I don't see any log file in `$HOME/.local/share/vlc`

Comment: Go to the messages window there's a more descriptive error message. (CTRL + M)

Comment: OP never replied to comment suggestion made 5+ years ago. OP hasn't signed on in 1+ year. Question is about EOL Ubuntu version. VTC as not reproducible.